# How do I assign a probability distribution to all combinations (4500+) of a single variable?

Tags: distributions, simulation, goodness-of-fit, excel, minitab

I'm trying to simulate the delivery times for a fast food restaurant (i.e. the time it takes the delivery guy to reach the client from the restaurant).

The locations of all clients are put in clusters called "sectors". These sectors are like neighborhoods, so all orders that fall in the same sector are assumed to have the same delivery time. Since taking a shortest route problem is out of the question, I have to simulate the time it takes to reach each sector (for which I do have the data for).

The problem is, each restaurant covers 300+ sectors, and then if we take into account that traffic levels vary across the day (say each hour, so from 6:00 AM to 9:00 PM you would have about 15 time intervals), we get 300*15 = 4,500 different combinations. And this is without even taking into account the different days of the week.

So my question is: how can I even begin to assign a probability distribution for each one of these combinations? Is there a way to make it faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find a probability distribution that seems to work generally, Gaussian would be a good start, and then you just need to estimate the two parameters of that distribution for each combination. For a Gaussian distribution, the MLE of the two parameters are the sample mean and unbiased sample variance, which are quite easy to calculate.